# Why self.__dict__ can trigger getattribute and instance.attribute can't?

Tags: python-3.x, descriptor

The proof verify that `self.__dict__`  can trigger `__getattribute__` in descriptor.

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __getattribute__(self,attr):
        print('in __getattribute__',attr)
        return  object.__getattribute__(self,attr)
    def __setattr__(self,attr,value):
        print('in __setattr__',attr)
        self.__dict__[attr] = value
        print('over')
```

Create an instance,i add some comments starting with `#` in the output info:

```
x = Room('r1')
# self.name = name in __init__ trigger __setattr__
in __setattr__ name  
# python interpreter read part of self.__dict__[attr] = value,extract self.__dict__ to trigger __getattribute__.
in __getattribute__ __dict__  
over
```

We saw that python interpreter can extract part of string in a whole line to trigger `__getattribute__` method.

```
class Sample:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __get__(self,instance,owner):
        print('get called')
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print('set called')

class Person:
    name = Sample('name')
```

Make an instance:

```
p = Person()
p.name
get called
```

`p.name` can trigger `__get__`

```
p.name = 'tom'
set called
```

For the command `p.name = 'tom'`,why python interpreter do not extract `p.name` invoke `__get__` and then make `p.name = 'tom'` invoke `__set__`? Why the output is not as below?

```
p.name = 'tom'
get called   # p.name  trigger
set called   # p.name = 'tom' trigger
```

@jsbueno,The default `__setattr__` will, ordinarily, create an entry in the instance `__dict__`,
but that one will be refereed to in native code, using the internal slots, and not be redirected through `__gettattribute__`.It is not true.

```
import time
class Room:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __getattribute__(self,attr):
        print('in __getattribute__',attr)
        return  object.__getattribute__(self,attr)
    def __setattr__(self,attr,value):
        print('in __setattr__',attr)
        time.sleep(3)
        self.__setattr__(attr, value)
        print('over')
```

If we write `self.__setattr__(attr, value)` instead of `super.__setattr__(attr, value)`,python interpreter extract `self.__setattr__` and redirect into `__gettattribute__`,then
parse `super.__setattr__(attr, value)` in the whole as `__setattr__` ,jump into `__setattr__` again,repeat without endness until you stop it by `ctl+c`.

```
x = Room('r1')
in __setattr__ name
in __getattribute__ __setattr__
in __setattr__ name
in __getattribute__ __setattr__
in __setattr__ name
in __getattribute__ __setattr__
in __setattr__ name
in __getattribute__ __setattr__
in __setattr__ name
in __getattribute__ __setattr__
in __setattr__ name
```

We draw some conclusion on data descriptor from above codes.
1.expressions without triggering `__getattribute__`.

```
super().__setattr__(attr, value)  
object.__setattr__(self,attr, value)  # i have checked
```

2.expressions with triggering `__getattribute__`.

```
self.__setattr__(attr, value)
self.__dict__[attr] = value
```

When `self.__setattr__` trigger `__getattribute__`,`__setattr__` was parsed as attr.
When `self.__dict__` trigger `__getattribute__`,`__dict__` was parsed as attr.
Puzzles remain here.
Puzzle1:
With same structure:

```
super().__setattr__(attr, value)  
object.__setattr__(self,attr, value)
self.__setattr__(attr, value)
```

,python interpreter parse the first two expressions as setting value for attribute,never triger `get` nor `set`,Why python interpreter read part of code snippet `self.__setattr__` in `self.__setattr__(attr, value)`,to trigger `get` (`__getattribute__`) in a hurry?

Puzzle2:
`self.__dict__[attr] = value` is an assignment in the whole,python interpreter extract part code snippet `self.__dict__` ,to trigger `get`,why don't python extract `self.name` in `self.name = name` in `__init__` to trigger `get` (`__getattribute__`) ,with same action ?

Puzzle3:
Dig more deeper on property management,more strange action shocked me.As the above codes show that `self.__setattr__(attr, value)` trigger `__getattribute__` in data descriptor,it trigger `set` instead of `get` in below code:

```
import time
class Room:
     def __init__(self,value):
         self.name = value  
     def get_name(self):
         print('in get')
         return self.__dict__['name']       
     def set_name(self, value):
         print('in set')
         time.sleep(3)
         self.__setattr__('name', value)
     name = property(get_name, set_name) 
r = Room('r1')
in set
in set
in set
in set
```

So i feel that some rules or logic still do not be summarized.

Answer (score 2):

Assignemts will trigger `__setattr__` for ordinary objects, and call the `__set__` method in descriptors, as you verified.

The only reason your first example runs `__getattribute__` to retrieve the instance `__dict__` is because *your* custom implementation of `__setattr__` does so.

The default `__setattr__` will, ordinarily, create an entry in the instance `__dict__`, but that one will be refereed to in native code, using the internal slots, and not be redirected through `__gettattribute__`.

You can verify this easily by using the default `__setattr__` implementation by callign `super()`, instead of creating a dict entry yourself:

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def __getattribute__(self,key):
        print('in __getattribute__',key)
        return  object.__getattribute__(self,key)
    def __setattr__(self,attr,value):
        print('in __setattr__',attr)
        super().__setattr__(attr, value)
        print('over')
```

And in the interactive interpreter:

```
In [35]: r = Room("blah")
in __setattr__ name
over
In [36]: r.name
in __getattribute__ name
Out[36]: 'blah'

In [37]: r.__dict__
in __getattribute__ __dict__
Out[37]: {'name': 'blah'}
```

So, the behavior you observed in your `__set__` in the descriptor is the ordinary behavior.

Comment: `self.__setattr__(attr, value) ` will  redirect  into `__gettattribute__`,i feel that some rules or logic still do not be summarized.

Comment: Many puzzles in my updated.